# R: NaiveBayes incrementally on a large data set

Tags: mysql, r

I have a large data set in a MySQL database (at least 11 GB of data). I would like to train a NaiveBayes model on the entire set and then test is against a smaller but also quite large data set (~3 GB).

The second part seems feasible - I assume that I would run the following in a loop:

```
data_test <- sqlQuery(con, paste("select * from test_data LIMIT 10000", "OFFSET", (i*10000) ))    
model_pred <- predict(model, data_test, type="raw")
```

...and then dump the predictions back to MySQL or a CSV.

How can I, however, train my model incrementally on such a large data set? I noticed in the R documentation of the function (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/e1071/docs/naiveBayes) that there is an addtional argument in the predict function "newdata" which suggests that incremental learning is possible. The predict function however will return the predictions and not a new model.

Please provide me with an example of how to incrementally train my model.

Comment: You could try the NaiveBayes function inside the RMOA package on github (https://github.com/jwijffels/RMOA). This allows to build naivebayes incrementally row by row.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you land me an simple example (code) of training row by row?

Comment: I tried installing the RMOA package (line: install_github("jwijffels/RMOA", subdir="RMOAjars/pkg")
) but get this error: * creating vignettes ...Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/i386/Rscript" --vanilla --default-packages= -e "tools::buildVignettes(dir = '.', tangle = TRUE)"' had status 1
 ERROR
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  pdflatex is not available
Calls: <Anonymous> -> texi2pdf -> texi2dvi
Execution halted
Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: There is an example using a tree and a boosted tree on that github page (NaiveBayes is even more simple as there are no parameters). You seem to be lacking pdflatex. Are you working on Windows. If so, you need to install Rtools & Miktex (see http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) before you can run install_github. If you are on Ubuntu install texlive before running install_github: sudo apt-get install texlive-full

Comment: I have RTools I will therefore add Miktex. I am running windows. Does this make any diff?